# Workflow: Email contents of file

Tags: oozie

I have a bunch of pig scripts that I'm running as a workflow in oozie. Some of the output files are very short and there are a couple I'd like to concatenate and include in the body of an email action. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: did you find an answer to this ? can you post it here ?

Answer (score 0):

Use  action and send an email from a script.

workflow.xml :

```
...
<shell>
  <exec>email_hdfs_file.sh</exec>

  <file>scripts/email_hdfs_file.sh</exec>
</shell>
...
```

Make sure you have scripts/email_hdfs_file.sh in the same folder in hdfs.

email_hdfs_file.sh :

```
#1 download and merge multiple files into one
hadoop fs -getmerge /path/to/your/files part-all.txt

#2 put a command that emails part-all.txt file here
```

It's up to you how to implement #2